# Is it possible to use regular expressions with OpenApi / Swagger @RequestParam?

Tags: regex, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I want to define a regular expression for a request parameter to be documented with Swagger. In fact I want to define the format of a filename. I s this possible using Annotations in Spring (Boot)?

Here:

```
   @Bean
    default OpenAPI customOpenApi() {

        return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info()
                .title("")
                .version("1.0")
                .description(""))
            .components(new Components()
                    .addParameters(
                            "api-version", new io.swagger.v3.oas.models.parameters.Parameter()
                            .name("api-version")
                            .required(Boolean.TRUE)
                            .allowEmptyValue(Boolean.FALSE)
                            .description("")
                            .in("header")
                            .schema(new io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema<String>().type("string").example("1.0.0"))
                    )
                    .addParameters(
                            "file-name", new io.swagger.v3.oas.models.parameters.Parameter()
                            .name("file-name")
                            .required(Boolean.TRUE)
                            .allowEmptyValue(Boolean.TRUE)
                            .description("Filename of the file to be imported in the following format: " +
                        "<ul>" +
                        " <li><b>yyyyMMdd_DocumentType_senderID_rexeiverID_xxx_version.xml</b></li>" +
                        "</ul>")
                            .in("header")
                            .schema(new io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema<Integer>().type("string").example("20210228_A14_123456789_987654321_xxx_123.xml"))
                    )
            );
    }
```

or here:

```
    ResponseEntity<ResponseBody> postData(
        @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
        @RequestAttribute(name = REQUST_ID, required = false) String requestId,
        @Parameter(name = API_VERSION_HEADER_PARAMETER) @RequestHeader(name = API_VERSION_HEADER_PARAMETER) String apiVersion,
        @Parameter(name = FILENAME_HEADER_PARAMETER) @RequestHeader(name = FILENAME_HEADER_PARAMETER) String fileName,

        @Validated @RequestBody RestRequestBody body
    );
```

Comment: [`Schema`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations/2.1.10/index.html?io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/Schema.html) has the `pattern` property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you use OpenAPI 3

You can use a pattern like this:

```
ssn:
  type: string
  pattern: '^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$'
```

Source: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#pattern

In the code this looks like this:

```
ResponseEntity<Order> getOrderById(@Pattern(regexp="^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$") @ApiParam(value = "ID of pet that needs to be fetched",required=true) @PathVariable("orderId") String orderId);
```

Comment: Yes, OpenApi 3.1. My fault: I am looking for a way to define it in the code-first approach using Java annotations.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, Simon. Many thanks. :-)

Comment: How to customise the error message that gets thrown when pattern validation fails?

Comment: I am also looking answer to the question of @Mumzee. How to customize the error message when a pattern match fails?